# Playing Audio File with notification in Tizen

Tags: audio, notifications, tizen, tizen-web-app

In a Tizen application I want to play an audio file when notification is posted and I have written below code.

```
function postNotification()
{
    try {
        var iconPath=tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().appInfo.iconPath;
          var myappInfo = tizen.application.getAppInfo();
          var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
          var notificationDict = {
                      content : "Alarm Playing",
                      iconPath : iconPath,
                      soundPath : "ab.mp3", 
                      vibration : true, 
                      thumbnails : "icon.png",
                      ledColor : "#FFFF00",
                      ledOnPeriod: 10000,
                      ledOffPeriod : 5000 ,
                      appId : myappInfo.id };  
          var myNotification = new tizen.StatusNotification("SIMPLE", "Simple notification", notificationDict);
          tizen.notification.post(myNotification);

     } catch (err) {
          alert(err.name + ": " + err.message);
     }
}
```

The file ab.mp3 is in the same folder with js file. But its not playing that audio. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: What Tizen version are you using and what SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on the js folder, the path should be:

```
soundPath : "js/ab.mp3"
```

Cause the default path is "project root" folder, you have to add the folder name of the resource, as in index.html we do:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```